# ajax json ответ символами \u0412\u0435\ вместо русских

Tags: jquery, ajax, массивы, json, битрикс

php

```
$data = array('name' => $name, 'price' => $price);
        $data = json_encode($data);

        print ($data);
```

js
$.ajax({

```
        type:'get',
        url: '/ajax/items_info.php',
        //dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        data:{'id':$item_id},
        response:'text',
        success:function (data) {
            //jQuery.parseJSON(data);
           console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Все это на битриксе, если это вообще имеет значение) когда передаю просто строки типа $name - русские символы печатает. Массив - u0412\u0435\u043d. Закомментированный код особо не помогает, дает ошибки.

Comment: попробуйте добавить в начале страницы index.php или что у вас там  
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.utf8');
Header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8");

Comment: Опцию `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` в `json_encode()` используйте.

Comment: былобы круто, но не помогло

Comment: JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE сработал. супер! спасибо.

Comment: success:function (data) {
               console.log(data[0]);- не могу вывести таким образом первый элемент массива, в чем дело?

Answer (score 0):

Это просто формат кодирования Unicode-символов. И JavaScript и PHP обычно нормально его понимают, и если вы на js напишете `alert("\u0412\u0435\u043d")`, то увидите "Вен".

Как уже указали в комментариях, используйте флаг `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` в `json_encode` чтоб отключить это.